# Subsampling/averaging over a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, subsampling

I have a numpy array with floats.

What I would like to have (if it is not already existing) is a function that gives me a new array of the average of every x points in the given array, like sub sampling (and opposite of interpolation(?)).

E.g. sub_sample(numpy.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]), 2) gives [1.5, 3.5, 5.5]

E.g. Leftovers can be removed, e.g. sub_sample(numpy.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]), 2) gives [1.5, 3.5]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Averaging over every n elements of a numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15956309/averaging-over-every-n-elements-of-a-numpy-array)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Using NumPy routines you could try something like

```
import numpy

x = numpy.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])

numpy.mean(x.reshape(-1, 2), 1) # Prints array([ 1.5,  3.5,  5.5])
```

and just replace the `2` in the `reshape` call with the number of items you want to average over.

**Edit**: This assumes that `n` divides into the length of `x`. You'll need to include some checks if you are going to turn this into a general function. Perhaps something like this:

```
def average(arr, n):
    end =  n * int(len(arr)/n)
    return numpy.mean(arr[:end].reshape(-1, n), 1)
```

This function in action:

```
>>> x = numpy.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
>>> average(x, 2)
array([ 1.5,  3.5,  5.5])

>>> x = numpy.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
>>> average(x, 2)
array([ 1.5,  3.5,  5.5])
```

Comment: This one works fine, except when the window size (2 in example above) is not a multiplication of the length of the array but I can make sure this is. Thanks!

Comment: thanks ... yes that was exactly what I also was thinking about.

Comment: Is there an easy way to generalize this to downsampling a single axis, in a multidimensional array?  e.g. average an array of shape [8,4] down to [4,4] ?

Comment: Could you provide a solution where i could enter a floating downsampling rate. E.g 2.7

Comment: @maniac If you have a question that isn't answered here, please post a new question, rather than commenting on an existing answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
def subsample(data, sample_size):
    samples = list(zip(*[iter(data)]*sample_size))   # use 3 for triplets, etc.
    return map(lambda x:sum(x)/float(len(x)), samples)

l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

print subsample(l, 2)
print subsample(l, 3)
print subsample(l, 5)
```

Gives:

```
[1.5, 3.5, 5.5]
[2.0, 5.0]
[3.0]
```

Comment: Thank you I will try it, however I hope there will be a numpy function because they tend to be around 10 times faster as most similar Python function.

Answer (score -1):

this is also a one line solution that works:

```
downsampled_a = [a[i:n+i].mean() for i in range(0,size(a),n)]
```

"a" is the vector with your data and "n" is your sampling step.

PS: `from numpy import *`

Comment: It returns `[1.5, 3.5, 5.0]` - not `[1.5, 3.5]` as desired by OP. Also use `np.size()` instead of importing all from `numpy`.

Comment: The above one-liner returns exactly what asked: [1.5, 3.5, 5.5] not [1.5, 3.5, 5.0]. The leftover -of course- can be removed (see the examples in the original question).

Comment: numpy.size() can be avoided. len() it is enough... (^_^)/*