# Numpy array mean each ten values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, mean

I have a numpy array with millions of values. It has only a dimension.
I'd like to return a new numpy array with the mean values of each tens.

What could be the solution?

Thanks for the support!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Averaging over every n elements of a numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15956309/averaging-over-every-n-elements-of-a-numpy-array)

Answer (score 2):

[`reshape`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html), sum, and divide by 10:

```
N = 10
a.reshape(-1,N).sum(1)/N
```

or, using [`numpy.mean`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html):

```
np.mean(a.reshape(-1,10), 1)
```

*NB. You need to ensure you array has a length that is a multiple of N. If not, slice to truncate or pad to add missing values*

example:

```
a = np.arange(10*20)
a.reshape(-1,10).sum(1)/10
```

output:

```
array([  4.5,  14.5,  24.5,  34.5,  44.5,  54.5,  64.5,  74.5,  84.5,
        94.5, 104.5, 114.5, 124.5, 134.5, 144.5, 154.5, 164.5, 174.5,
       184.5, 194.5])
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose 'a' is your array with million or so entries, then you can get desired output as follows:

```
x = np.array([np.mean(a[i:i+10]) for i in range(0, len(a), 10)])
```

Answer (score 0):

If your array is not well balanced, fill your array with `nan` and use `np.nanmean` to calculate the mean:

```
a = np.arange(123)
N = 10
M = int(np.ceil(len(a) / 10) * 10 - len(a))
b = np.nanmean(np.concatenate([a, np.full(M, np.nan)]).reshape(-1, N), axis=1)
```

Output:

```
>>> b
array([  4.5,  14.5,  24.5,  34.5,  44.5,  54.5,  64.5,  74.5,  84.5,
        94.5, 104.5, 114.5, 121. ])
```

121 = (120 + 121 + 122 + nan + nan + nan + nan + nan + nan + nan) / 3